# Delphi - How to Register File extension for auto-open?

Tags: delphi, extension-methods, tmemo

How can i auto-open a custom extension in my Delphi app ? I'm trying to make application 
that loads text files but with a different extension.

Example : `Text.DZ` | all i want is when i click the file with `.DZ` Extension it opens my app automatically and loads the text inside into the `memo1.lines.text`.

I know that i have to register my new custom extension but i have no idea how to do it and 
load the text into my app.

Also if you can include a source-code example that would be awesome.

Any help will be much appreciated ! and 
Sorry for my newbiness and bad English explanation but i hope you guys understand me (^-^)/.

Comment: Note: the answer there also briefly covers what to do if you want to set this up system-wide.

Comment: That does not necessarily address OP's question. It's not clear whether he just wants to do this for his app running on his own system, or if it's for product purposes. There are two distinct solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a way to do it programmatically, although I don't recall how off the cuff.

That said, if you're just wanting to do it for your own personal use, not for a piece of software you'll be distributing to others, then the easiest way is to use Windows Explorer: click the data file you want, then right-click and select Open With -> ... you'll probably need to select the Other... option at the bottom. That will bring up a dialog box that lets you choose your app. There should also be a checkbox somewhere that says something like "Make Default" or "Always Open With This" or something along those lines. Make sure that box is checked. Then click OK a couple of times and you're off to the races.

But you'll also need to set up your app to read the filename from the command line. You use ParamStr and ParamCount for this.

```
for i := 0 to ParamCount do
  ShowMessage('Parameter '+IntToStr(i)+' = '+ParamStr(i));
```

When you double-click on the data file, it will open your app and pass this filename as ParamStr(1). So when you get it, simply do something like this:

```
memo1.lines.LoadFromFile( ParamStr(1) );
```

Use this as a STARTING POINT (it won't compile if you just copy-and-paste!):

```
procedure TMyForm234:FormCreate( blah blah )
begin
  if ParamCount > 0 then
    theMemo.Lines.LoadFromFile( ParamStr(1) );
end;
```

Comment: Thanks David bro ! but where do i put the code, on what event ? onformshow or what ? Nd i don't wwant messages to display during loading the file :D thanks mate for the help

Comment: David Schwartz So how can i run this silently or on what event should i put these codes ;c sorry i am so noob and sorry for being stopid beginner ;c

Comment: I think people here are assuming you're looking for a solution for a production piece of software that you need to distribute to billions of people. It would be really GREAT if you'd clarify for folks whether this question is JUST FOR YOUR OWN PERSONAL NEEDS, or for a program you're DISTRIBUTING TO THE MASSES.

Comment: I'd put it in the FormCreate event handler. NOT FormShow.

Comment: Yep i'm planning to distribute it to people ! It would be useful app but this is my last issue i need to solve it :D

Comment: Thanks David i think i'v found it ! <3 
this should do the trick :/ 

`procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
i : Integer;
begin

    for i := 1 to paramcount do memo1.lines.LoadFromFile( ParamStr(1) );`

Comment: No, NOT FORMSHOW!!! You only want it called ONCE when the program STARTS UP. That's what FormCreate is for. FormShow is called EVERY TIME THE FORM IS SHOWN. It's not as often as FormActivate, but it's very frequently more than once. Also, the loop is there to show you want the ParamStr arguments are. You only want to call it once. What you have will re-load the first file (ParamStr(1)) for however many files are on the list, which most of the time will be one anyway.

Comment: If you're going to distribute this to people, then you also want to follow the instructions given earlier. Although, while I don't like that solution, I cannot think of the way I solved it before, and can't find a code example of it either.